# How can I make a button appear on top of another one without using position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to render a control that will appear on the right side, on top of another control that takes 100% of the width of the container.

An example of what I want (with buttons):

[image]

I tried to achieve this by setting a high value for the `z-index` attribute of the small button. This does not work though.

My attempt:

```css
.mydiv {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    <button style="width:100%; height:30px;">big button</button>
    <button style="width:80px; height:20px; z-index:99;">smallbutton</button>
</div>
```

However I get this:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this using flexbox and without `position:absolute` if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a job of CSS grid where you can put both elements on the same area:

```css
.mydiv {
  display: grid;
}

.mydiv>button {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <button style="width:100%; height:30px;">big button</button>
  <button style="width:80px; height:20px;place-self: center end">smallbutton</button>
</div>
```